# How to write a slicker macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've put together a macro that is meant to increase dates by one in an array of 7 cells ("B2:H2"), (reflecting 7d in a week) once B2 value is changed.

I am sure there is a better way of writing this:

```
Sub Date_Increment

' increases consecutive days by 1

Range("c2").Value = Range("b2").Value + 1
Range("d2").Value = Range("c2").Value + 1  
Range("e2").Value = Range("d2").Value + 1  
Range("f2").Value = Range("e2").Value + 1  
Range("g2").Value = Range("f2").Value + 1  
Range("h2").Value = Range("g2").Value + 1

End Sub
```

This feels a bit too Neanderthal.

Much appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not just use a formula in cells `C2:H2`: `=B2+1`, and change the date in `B2` only.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop. Try-

```
Sub Date_Increment()
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 7
        Cells(2, 2 + i) = Cells(2, 2).Value + i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub Date_Increment    
' increases consecutive days by 1
    Dim i as Long
    For i=1 to 6
        Range("c2").Cells(i,1).Value = Range("b2").Cells(i,1).Value + 1
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Note: `Range("c2")` implies `ActiveSheet.Range("c2")` so unless this is code under a specific worksheet you need to be aware that it will only work if the sheet holding the dates is the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

See if below code is useful for you.

```
Sub Date_Increment2()
    With Range("C2:H2")
        .Formula = "=B2+1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Personally, I'd leave cell C2 onwards as formula cells as then any change in B2 would get reflected immediately.